# How do I add an init script to my RPM

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, rpm-spec

I want to add an init script to my RPM in order to run the program from a terminal just by typing its name, there's one more thing which I am confused about and that is:-
where are these files located: pre, post, preun, postun, are they written directly into the spec file after adding a line %pre etc.

I've been through the following links however I couldn't find a solution: -

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:ScriptletSnippets#Systemd

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Systemd?#Filesystem_locations

Updated===============================================================
I am doing it on CentOS 6.8 and here's the spec file I created so far:-

```
# RPM package for xyz.
%define   __spec_install_post %{nil}
%define   debug_package %{nil}
%define   __os_install_post %{_dbpath}/brp-compress

Summary: XYZ program.
Name: xyz
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
License: GPL+
Group: Development/Tools

SOURCE0 : %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
URL: https://wwwDOTxyzDOTcom/

BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root
%description
%{summary}
%prep
%setup -q
%build
# Empty section.

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p  %{buildroot}
# in builddir
cp -a * %{buildroot}
%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}
%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%config(noreplace) %{_sysconfdir}/%{name}/%{name}.conf
%{_bindir}/*

%changelog
* Mon Mar 6 2017  xyz <noemail@noemail.com> 1.0-1
- First Build
EOF
```

but still confused as to how do I start the program from a terminal just by typing its name.

Comment: Will appreciate any help...

Answer (score 1):

You mean SYSV init files? Or systemD unit files? Different logic, but ok - at the end they are both files. In different location, but just files.

You have to do:

```
%{?systemd_requires}
BuildRequires: systemd

%install
cp -a path/in/your/targz/SOMESERVICE.service %{buildroot}%{_unitdir}/

%post
%systemd_post SOMESERVICE.service

%preun
%systemd_preun SOMESERVICE.service

%postun
%systemd_postun_with_restart SOMESERVICE.service

%files
%{_unitdir}/SOMESERVICE.service
```

For SYSV there would be little bit different paths and different snippets in %post* and %preun.

Comment: Ok, does it mean init.d is used under debian and systemD under RHL?

Comment: I have a binary which I have compiled on eclipse (centos), I want to create an RPM to install that binary, all I want my RPM to do is, place the binary and configuration files in place, which it's doing absolutely fine but what more I need is, the ability to be able to run that binary file by typing just the name no matter which directory I'm in. So if the app name is xyz , I want to write xyz anywhere in the terminal and execute the xyz program. Thanks in advance. Sorry I don't really know what I need as I am new to linux.

Comment: Centos6 and "Debian stable" use SYSV init, Centos 7 and "Debian testing" use SystemD. I am not sure which you target.